# How can knowing test data improve the performance of face recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, pattern-recognition, unsupervised-learning

I don't think knowing face recognition is necessary to answer this question, any suggestions are welcome. For face verification problems, usually images are first converted into fixed length vectors through neural networks, then we use some similarity measure to tell whether two images are of the same person.

To evaluate the performance, currently we use a number of images to query against an image base (about 50k images of different people, not used in training) and see its roc curve or top-n accuracy.

**My question is, if I know in advance all the images in the base, is there anything to do to improve the performance?**